# React Native Navigator custom button onPress

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm using react-native-navigation as my navigation in an app and I have used the left / right button option (static navigatorButtons) to implement some buttons on each side of the navbar which I can use with onNavigatorEvent(event) and check which one was pressed with event.id

Those work fine but now I have added some custom buttons in the middle using a component (Custom Bar). The issue is I have no idea how to detect onPress of those buttons. The onNavigatorEvent(event) doesn't seem to detect them and not sure how to do this.

Basically I want to display listA if leftButton is pressed or listB if rightButton is pressed but don't know how to listen to the onPress event

Custom Bar

```
import stuff needed

export default class TopBar extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        leftPressed: true,
        rightPressed: false
      };

      this.leftButton = this.leftButton.bind(this);
      this.rightButton = this.rightButton.bind(this);
   }

   leftButton(){
      this.setState({
         leftPressed: true,
         rightPressed: false
      })
   }

   rightButton(){
      this.setState({
         leftPressed: false,
         rightPressed: true
      })
   }

   render() {
      return (
        <View style={Styles.container}>
           <View style = {[Styles.wrapper, {borderTopLeftRadius: 20, borderBottomLeftRadius: 20}]}>
           <TouchableOpacity style={[Styles.button, {alignSelf: 'flex-start'}]} onPress={ this.leftButton }>
              <Text style={[Styles.text, this.state.leftPressed && Styles.textSelected]}>All Tasks</Text>
           </TouchableOpacity>
           </View>
           <View style = {[Styles.wrapper, {borderTopRightRadius: 20, borderBottomRightRadius: 20}]}>
           <TouchableOpacity style={[Styles.button, {alignSelf: 'flex-start'}]} onPress={ this.rightButton }>
              <Text style={[Styles.text, this.state.rightPressed && Styles.textSelected]}>My Tasks</Text>
           </TouchableOpacity>
           </View>
        </View>
      );
   }
}
```

Main Screen

```
import other stuff needed
import TopBar from '../_shared/components/TopBar';

Navigation.registerComponent('task.TopBar', () => TopBar);
class TaskListComponent extends BaseView {
   static navigatorButtons = {
       rightButtons: [
           {
            id: 'Filter',
            icon: require('../_shared/components/Images/tune.png'),
           },
           {
            id: 'Search',
            icon: require('../_shared/components/Images/search.png'),
           }
       ],
       leftButtons: [
           {
            id: 'Create',
            icon: require('../_shared/components/Images/plus.png'),
           },
       ]
   }

   constructor(props) {
       super(props);
this.props.navigator.setOnNavigatorEvent(this.onNavigatorEvent.bind(this));
    this.state = {
        tasklist: props.TaskList || null
    };

   onNavigatorEvent(event) {
       if (event.type == 'NavBarButtonPress') {
           if (event.id == 'Create') {
               this.createTask()
           }
           if (event.id == 'Search') {
               this.searchTask()
           }
           if (event.id == 'Filter') {
               this.filterTask()
           }
       }
   }

//code for the left/right buttons goes here

   componentDidMount() {
       this.props.navigator.setStyle({
           navBarCustomView: 'task.TopBar',
           navBarComponentAlignment: 'center',
       });
   }

   render() {
       if (TopBar leftPressed true) { //I know this is wrong just explaining the logic
           return (
               <View>
                   //some stuff
               </View>
           );
       } else {
           return (
               <View>
                   //other stuff
               </View>
           )
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a button is pressed, dispatch a [DeepLink](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/deep-links) and handle the link in the screen. You can dispatch DeepLink statically for example:

`Navigation.handleDeepLink({link: 'button1Pressed'});`